# How to read actual destination address from sk_buff?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm writing a netfilter module to drop packets based on destination IP check.

I registered a nf hook as

```
nfho_out.hook = hook_func_out;
nfho_out.hooknum = NF_INET_LOCAL_OUT;
nfho_out.pf = PF_INET;
nfho_out.priority = NF_IP_PRI_FIRST;
nf_register_hook(&nfho_out);
```

This is my nf hook function

```
    unsigned int hook_func_out(unsigned int hooknum, struct sk_buff *skb, const struct net_device *in, const struct net_device *out, int (*okfn)(struct sk_buff *)) {
        struct iphdr *ip_header = (struct iphdr *)skb_network_header(skb);
        struct udphdr *udp_header;
        struct tcphdr *tcp_header;
        struct list_head *p;

        unsigned int src_ip = (unsigned int)ip_header->saddr;
        unsigned int dest_ip = (unsigned int)ip_header->daddr;
        unsigned int src_port = 0;
        unsigned int dest_port = 0;

        if (ip_header->protocol==17) {
                udp_header = (struct udphdr *)skb_transport_header(skb);
                src_port = (unsigned int)ntohs(udp_header->source);
        } else if (ip_header->protocol == 6) {
                tcp_header = (struct tcphdr *)skb_transport_header(skb);
                src_port = (unsigned int)ntohs(tcp_header->source);
                dest_port = (unsigned int)ntohs(tcp_header->dest);
        }

        printk(KERN_INFO "OUT packet info: src ip: %u, src port: %u; dest ip: %u, dest port: %u; proto: %u\n", src_ip, src_port, dest_ip, dest_port, ip_header->protocol);
        printk(KERN_DEBUG "IP addres = %pI4  DEST = %pI4\n", &src_ip, &dest_ip);
....
....
}
```

I opened google.com in web browser, but I cannot get the actual destinatio IP address that google.com resolves to. The problem is I'm always getting some strange IP addresses (as I suspect proxy or dns server) instead of the actual IP address.

How can I get the actual destination address in the nf hook function?

Comment: Are you sure your web browser connects to the IP you think it does? Google is known from using weird addresses (save for 8.8.8.8)...

Comment: I'm always getting destination address as 10.169.95.255. My IP address is 10.169.95.73

Comment: Whatever website I browse I'm getting 10.169.95.255 as destination IP from IP header

Comment: Try to connect directly: "telnet some_wbesite.com 80"   and then "get / http/1.0"

Comment: Perhaps looking at [`iptables` sources](https://git.netfilter.org/iptables/tree/iptables/nft-ipv4.c#n180) may be of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code seems good without logic error. your problem is rooted either in network structure(explained below) or web server machine. Now servers can detect whether query is from web browsers or some other software
you can not do this sort of filtering at end user internet pc. The problem is that from your pc to google server there is a sea of obstacles to cross over like proxies, router's settings, firewalls/gateways. It seems that your pc is only getting own local network gateway/proxy address 
Some suggestions to come out of this problem

test your app from different network to confirm your own firewall/proxy is not the cause of problem
if you have some resources around you make simple internet using router and switch and try to access websites hosted on same your own internet. if you dont have hardware then try some network emulators/simulators to test your code. NS2/NS3 and OMNET are free with lot of tutorials.

The crest of problem is that you are protected with firewall at some level. your `10.169.95.255` is local IP which means you are not able to cross your own network.

Answer (score 4):

I do not see any problem with the code snippet you posted.

When you open www.google.com in web browser, first the DNS is resoved and later HTTP messages are exchanged. Hence you will see that during DNS resolution, the `dest_ip` is **GATEWAY/DNS SERVER** ip. Once DNS is resolved, in further messages, the `dest_ip` is always the resolved IP of www.google.com.

First check what does www.google.com resolve to by issuing the following command on the terminal:

```
[s.roy@roy ~]$ nslookup www.google.com
Server:     192.168.1.1
Address:    192.168.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 216.58.220.36
```

As you can see, www.google.com is resolved to **216.58.220.36** by the DNS server **192.168.1.1** which is also the default gateway in my case. Note that during ***nslookup*** my `dest_ip` is 192.168.1.1.

After DNS resolution, my system will send TCP and HTTP messages with `dest_ip` as **216.58.220.36**.

**test.c**

```c
static struct nf_hook_ops nfho_out;

static unsigned int hook_func_out(unsigned int hooknum,
                                  struct sk_buff *skb,
                                  const struct net_device *in,
                                  const struct net_device *out,
                                  int (*okfn)(struct sk_buff *))
{

        struct iphdr *ip_header = (struct iphdr *)skb_network_header(skb);
        struct udphdr *udp_header;
        struct tcphdr *tcp_header;
        struct list_head *p;

        unsigned int src_ip = (unsigned int)ip_header->saddr;
        unsigned int dest_ip = (unsigned int)ip_header->daddr;
        unsigned int src_port = 0;
        unsigned int dest_port = 0;

        if (ip_header->protocol==17) {
                udp_header = (struct udphdr *)skb_transport_header(skb);
                src_port = (unsigned int)ntohs(udp_header->source);
        } else if (ip_header->protocol == 6) {
                tcp_header = (struct tcphdr *)skb_transport_header(skb);
                src_port = (unsigned int)ntohs(tcp_header->source);
                dest_port = (unsigned int)ntohs(tcp_header->dest);
        }

        printk(KERN_DEBUG "IP addres = %pI4  DEST = %pI4\n", &src_ip, &dest_ip);

        return NF_ACCEPT;

}


static int __init test_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Loading \n");

    nfho_out.hook = hook_func_out;
    nfho_out.hooknum = NF_INET_LOCAL_OUT;
    nfho_out.pf = PF_INET;
    nfho_out.priority = NF_IP_PRI_FIRST;
    nf_register_hook(&nfho_out);

    return 0;
}

static void __exit test_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Unloading \n");
    nf_unregister_hook(&nfho_out);


}

module_init(test_init);
module_exit(test_exit);
```

Roy